# C .Scan specific part of line from a file and assign it to some variable

Tags: c, file, scanf

if I have this data in a file :

> Mercure 99842 1 18 2001 5 30 1991 16 12.5
>
> Mazda 123961 2 20 1993 6 15 1993 19.3 16.7

and I'm interested in , say, just the third number of each line, and I want to store it in an array.

What I used to do , is to use some variables to store all the values in the line , and then I pick the one I'm interested in .
for example :

```
while(fscanf(file,"%s %d %d %d %d %d %d %f %f",a,&b,&array[i],&d,&e,&r,&t,&g,&h)!=EOF)
     {i++;}
```

array[i] is storing the value that I'm interested in , and the other variables are just to mach the format , I do not need them .

Is there any better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*` to have `fscanf()` read values and throw them away.

```
while(fscanf(file,"%*s %*d %d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*f %*f",&array[i])!=EOF)
     {i++;}
```

Comment: How can I avoid a space ? , I mean , If I have : 
Mercure Mazda 99842 1 18 
and I want to read "Mercure Mazda " into one char array . How can I do that  using scanf and %s  ?

Comment: It should be very hard task, so you should use another way such as using `%c`, reading characters one-by-one, and parsing the input by yourself.